# Redireccionar a Http en vez de https

Tags: php, http, iis, https, ssl

Mi problema es que estoy usando WebSockets y para conectar con mi servidor necesito usar ws:// pero me da error porque no es seguro, luego intento cambiar y usar wss:// pero no me funciona así.

Entonces la única solución que tengo es dejar de usar https:// y usar http:// pero la opción que tengo es cloudflare SSL, para usarlo en https:// lo dejo en modo flexible pero si lo apago en mi navegador sale el error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
y sigue redireccionando a https://

¿Como puedo hacer que redireccione a http:// siempre?

Utilizo PHP en el sitio con Framework Laravel 5.1 y IIS

Comment: Prueba a redireccionar desde el htaccess

Comment: Utilizo IIS y no me funcionan

Comment: Para configurar los redireccionamientos en IIS debes utilizar `web.config` ya que si bien estas utilizando PHP los .htaccess no están habilitados. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si el servicio de hosting que usas está configurado para redirigir las solicitudes HTTP a HTTPS, las respuestas del servidor a Cloudflare están encriptadas y dado que Cloudflare está esperando tráfico HTTP, continuará reenviando la misma solicitud, lo que resulta en un bucle de redirección. Esto hace que tu navegador muestre ese error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

Puedes hacer esto para eliminar las redirecciones HTTPS en tu servidor.
con un .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# Esto habilitará las capacidades de reescritura

RewriteCond% {HTTPS}! = On
# Esto comprueba que la conexión no sea HTTPS

RewriteRule ^ /? Secure /(.*) https: //% {SERVER_NAME} / secure / $ 1 [R, L]
# Esta regla redirigirá a todos los usuarios que usen cualquier parte de / secure / a 
la misma ubicación pero que usen HTTPS.
http://www.example.com/secure/ a https://www.example.com/secure/
# Esto significa que si no quiere forzar HTTPS para todos los directorios, puede 
forzarlo para una subsección específica del sitio.
```